# Two csv in solr search

Tags: solr, fuzzy-search

Hi i have two csv files. I would like to combine them according to their similarities. I can put them in two cores and use a fuzzy search if it won't work. Anyone have an idea how to do this. I'm new to solr search. Do I have to write manageschema code in this case?

Comment: What's your definition of "according to their similarities"? Do you have any examples of matches you want to produce? It might be more straight forward to put one of the files into Solr, and use the other file as queries to run against Solr to create a complete output.

Comment: According to their similarities, that is, for example, is there any typo or the data agree in some percentage, that is, for example, 70% match. I have one file loaded in solr, how to create a query using a second file to join them?

Comment: What's your definition of 70% match? "typo" is also very vague - do you have an example of what you want to match against? The common thing is, as you say, a fuzzy search against the values .. but that will probably give you false positives somewhere as well. That might not be an issue - so create fuzzy searches from csv2 and run them against a Solr core with csv1?

Comment: In csv1 I have columns: id, city, street, code, key1. In csv2 I have columns: id_prod, name, quantity, key2. I want to match them based on key1 and key2. So if key1 = key2 then csv1 columns are added to csv2. If in csv1 I have the key1 city_street_zip_code and in the key2 I have city_strets_zip_code, he will match them to me, because they match in some percentage. Where should I put the fuzzy search? w manage-schema? I have a question how to add a csv file using fuzzy search? Do you have an example somewhere or a tutorial, anything? I'm new to solr.

Comment: Index the reference file (csv1) into Solr, pick a programming language you're comfortable with and a suitable Solr client library, then iterate over csv2 and run each query against Solr as a fuzzy query (`~<edit distance>`) and output the new csv with those fields that have similarities. If you need to perform fuzzy matches _on field names_ as well, I strongly advice you to map those field names manually instead (i.e. that `city_strets_zip_code` is the same as `city_street_zip_code`. Additionally I'm not sure if zip codes are a good candidate for fuzzy search, as they're usually numeric.

Comment: Ok. So I do everything in manageschema and solrco fig.xml? I'm sorry to make sure I understand correctly.

Comment: No, fuzzy searches are given when making your query against Solr. It asks Lucene / Solr to perform a fuzzy match for matching tokens - in effect giving an edit distance (how many letters can be added / deleted / changed for it to still be considered a hit). The syntax is for example `street~1` which would give hits for `stret`. This is given as part of your query on query time, and not in configuration or your schema. However, how the input text is processed to tokens is configured in the schema.

Comment: Fuzzy searches are given when you make the query - you do not configure anything in the schema. You index csv1, then make a small program that iterate over csv2, looking up each line with the proper query to Solr - Append `~2` to your query term to get a fuzzy query with edit distance 2. If you want to do phonetic search etc. that require pre-processing, then you'll need to configure a specific field for your need in the schema. You'll have to add more data and examples to your question if you want a more extensive answer.